# How to get data from different microservice?

Tags: database, microservices

I have one microservice named `UserRegistration` for user creation, another microservice named `Billing` where able to show the billing details for users.

After a new user is being created, it will send `userId` from  `UserRegistration` to `Billing` through message queue like Apache Kafka or RabbitMq. Since these 2 microservices has different database, `Billing` microservice only has `userId`, how `Billing` able to retrieve the user details like name, age, address? Through REST API in `UserRegistration`?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid duplication of data (with the associated risk of working with stale data) using a `UserRegistration` service makes most sense indeed. Since both services are apparently under your control you could define an endpoint in `UserRegistration` that delivers exactly the data needed by `Billing`, unless such an endpoint already exists, of course.

Comment: what is the endpoint you mean? (REST call?, messaging queue?) sorry i can't really imagine how's the flow for the endpoint in `UserRegistration`

Comment: REST call, sorry that my wording was vague. `Billing` will need name and address essentially only when bills are being sent, so getting these fields just when needed using a REST endpoint will ensure that only up-to-date data will be used.

Answer (score 2):

If the billing service needs other data than it actually holds itself, what is the value of using a microservice here? If billing cannot run when UserRegistration is down, you have a tightly coupled big ball of mud.

So, ask yourself: which business value does the billing service supply, under which circumstances, and when? After you have answered the question, you basically have the following possibilities:

- scratch the billing service alltogeher, as it is part of a more general UserService
- depend on the UserRegistration service and do live queries by whatever method strikes your fancy
- transfer all necessary data to the billing service, and deal with the risk of stale data

Comment: thanks, but how those companies like Amazon, or Google do microservices, i mean, i don't think it is possible to eliminate the dependencies between 2 services(even the slightest) regardless of how well you design it right?

Comment: @hades It is possible. The big question is: *why* do you use microservices? Microservices may well be used to utilize computing power dynamically (i.e. have a fat common database and dynamically add images which do CPU number crunching) OR to cut your application into vertical slices. For the second approach, a microservice should (ideally, seldom achieved) always be able to run standalone without the other serivces being present.